# I'm having a problem with my little project

Tags: c++

So, i'm doing a little "virtual friend" kind of project:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hey!\n";
    std::cout << "My name is Bob! Hope I can be your friend! :D\n";
    std::cout << "But before all of my questions... would you like to be my friend?\n\n";
    std::cout << "Select your answer: YES or NO? ";
    string yes;
    string no;
    if (std::cin >> yes){
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "GOOD! Thank you for letting me know more of you! :D\n";
        std::cout << "Then, I'll start with some simple questions!\n";
        std::cout << "So tell me, what is your name?\n\n";
        std::cout << "My name is: ";
        string name;
        std::cin >> name;
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "GOOD! So your name is " << name << ", such a nice name! :)\n";
        std::cout << "So, " << name << "... I feel like I can only talk to someone once they tell me their age...\n";
        std::cout << "I would love to know, how old are u " << name << "?\n\n";
        std::cout << "I am: ";
        int age;
        std::cin >> age;
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "Hehe! Nice so you are " << age << " years old! :D\n";
        std::cout << "Very good!\n";
    } else if (std::cin >> no){
        std::cout << "Oh... I'm sorry if I bothered you...\n";
        std::cout << "See you one day then! :D\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm having a problem with my code, and I can't find what is wrong..!
Supposedly, "Bob" starts asking questions after the user inputs a "yes", but in the case of a "no" he has to answer the following:

```
std::cout << "Oh... I'm sorry if I bothered you...\n";
std::cout << "See you one day then! :D\n";
```

I don't know why, but whenever I choose "yes" or "no", "Bob" starts making the questions, as you can see here:

[When I choose YES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8wtT.png)

[When I choose NO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT4Yw.png)

Can someone help me with this..?
I would really love that! (also some tips to improve the code).

Comment: `cin >> yes` will be true regardless of what exactly the user entered. You need to read the string into a variable and then compare the string itself to "yes" or "no".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you wanted something closer to

```
string user_input;
std::cin >> user_input;

if (user_input == "yes")
{
    // yes case
}
else if (user_input == "no")
{
    // no case
}
```

Comment: The `else if` statement can be replaced to `else` directly too, because there's no other option's required. Isn't it?

Comment: @LinuXMan In their example yes, in general I don't know, maybe they'll add more options?

Comment: OMG!

Thank you! @CoryKramer, really, thank you! :D

Comment: Thank you for the info @LinuXMan, will change that! :D

Comment: @CoryKramer no, it's just those two options, my problem is solved, thank u! :D

Comment: @LinuXMan Defaulting to `no` could be dangerous, depending on the question. If the question is "_Do you want to be my friend?_" - and if someone answers  `ues` - imagine the drama if that's interpreted as `no`.